# Browser submit form Html <input type file generates request that Ubuntu Tomcat Apache server rejects

Tags: ubuntu, servlets, file-upload, https, tomcat9

I have a Java servlet app running on Ubuntu 20.04.2 in Tomcat9 apache. The servlets are required to run using https transport. I am using a self signed certificate to enable https/TLS on Tomcat9.

The servlet attempts to upload a file using a form that includes an html input tag with type file.

On my local area network, tomcat is running on the machine with ip4 address 10.0.0.200.

If I access the servlet from a browser on the same machine ( example ip4 address 10.0.0.200) as the tomcat server is running (example url https://10.0.0.200:8443/MyServlet), it works fine and the file is uploaded.

If I access the servlet from a browser on a  machine other than where the tomcat server is running (example from machine with ip4 address 10.0.0.30) the post request from form submit button **never reaches the servlet** (example url https://10.0.0.200:8443/MyServlet from machine 10.0.0.30).

The browser (FireFox) reports:
"An error occurred during a connection to 10.0.0.200:8443.
PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem."

Why does this not work?

This is recorded form post:

```
    POST /TempClientServlet/TempResult undefined
Host: 24.63.181.39:8443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------3698066889622667783588722062
Content-Length: 970929
Origin: https://24.63.181.39:8443
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://24.63.181.39:8443/TempClientServlet/TempResult
Cookie: user_name=ccervo; textCookie=ccervo; JSESSIONID=401E418CE0A56EFB5A34784DE97DC996
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

This is the web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TempClientServlet</display-name>
  <absolute-ordering />
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>TempClient</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <session-config>
    <cookie-config>
      <http-only>true</http-only>
      <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
  </session-config>
       
 <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secured page</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>          
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee> 
    </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
</web-app>
```

This is the server.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
--><!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
 <Server port="8081" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->
    <Connector connectionTimeout="20000"
     port="8080"
     protocol="HTTP/1.1"
     redirectPort="8443"
     />
     <!-- uncomment this to run servlets secure ie. https -->
      <Connector SSLEnabled="true"
       clientAuth="false"
        keystoreFile="/home/foobar/.keystore"
        keystorePass="changeit"
        maxThreads="200"
        port="8443"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        scheme="https"
        secure="true" 
        sslProtocol="TLS"
        />
    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    
            <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
                 Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
            <!--
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
            -->
    
            <!-- Access log processes all example.
                 Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
                 Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"/>
    
          <Context docBase="TempClientServlet" path="/TempClientServlet" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TempClientServlet"/>
          <Context path="/TempClientServlet/images" docBase="/var/opt/TempClientServletimages" crossContext="true"/>
          <Context docBase="Temp_Service" path="/Temp_Service" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Temp_Service"/>
          <Context docBase="Temp_ServiceClient" path="/Temp_ServiceClient" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Temp_ServiceClient"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet is not broken. Its operating correctly. The behavior is the result of extra stringent user agent security around the HTML "<input" tag with type "file".
When the user agent (browser) is on the same physical machine as the servlet server (Tomcat) the user agent relaxes security requirements and the servlet runs as expected the form successfully uploads files.
When the user agent (browser) is run on machine other than the machine the servlet server (Tomcat) is running. The user agent detects that the servlet was run through an https/TLS connection established under a "self signed certificate". Even though the user has been warned and accepted the "self signed certificate", the user agent considers it "insecure" and reports the error:

"PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified."

So the solutions are:

1. register a domain and purchase an authenticated certificate
2. run the servlets insecure using http
3. live with the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a 100% answer, but getting close enough that I'll get there on my own.

Steps to getting answer:

1. I wrote a tunnel/proxy that connects user agent (browser) to tomcat running
   my servlets and logs all TCP traffic between the two.
2. Added debug code to my servlets to eliminate use of session id and cookies.
   I'll restore this after I've found the bug.
3. Configured server.xml in Eclipse create connectors on ports 8080 and 8443 that
   are HTTP connectors.
4. Configured web.xml for servlets to allow http access.
   Caveats and suggestions:
   If your attempting to debug a secure servlet there are many pitfalls to avoid.
5. If you attempt to debug the servlet from Eclipse, be aware of these pitfalls.
   a) The Eclipse debugger runs Tomcat in a different environment than the Tomcat
   service is run. Specifically the Tomcat service is sandboxed. Tomcat run
   by Eclipse debugger is not. This may cause servlets to behave wildly
   differently when run in debugger and run via service.
   b) Linux, Ubuntu, runs Tomcat as a service under the user name "tomcat". Eclipse
   debugger on Ubuntu runs Tomcat under the user name of the user starting
   Eclipse. This may cause servlets to behave wildly
   differently when run in debugger and run via service.
6. If you switch between http and https while debugging be aware of these pitfalls.
   a) If your servlet uses J2EE session and/or cookies, be aware that the servlet container's behavior depends on settings in the applicable web.xml (application's and/or server). If the web.xml specifies a security constraint with transport guarantee confidential, then the servlet container
   sets the "secure" and "http/only" attributes on all cookies (including
   jsession cookie). If there is no constraint servlet container does not set "secure" and/or "http/only" on cookies. The http specification says user agents, browsers, will
   only pass/return secure cookies if the transport is secure (https/tls). This may
   cause servlets to lose session and behave wildly differently when accessed using http vs.
   https.
   b) If you debug using a user agent on the same physical machine as your
   servlet server, the http specification says user agents can pass secure
   cookies even if the transport is NOT https and is not secure. This may
   cause servlets to behave wildly differently when accessed using via
   a user agent running on the same machine as the servlet server.
   So after educating myself on all these pitfalls, I now have my servlets running through an http tunnel. I can observer all the TCP traffic. Running with user agent and servlet server on different machines; running in Eclipse debugger; running in HTTP; running with use of cookies and session removed; my servlets are running **perfectly no issues** (just slow a result of logging by the http tunnel). I now need to restore server.xml and web.xml to use https; restore use of session and cookies and determine why that configuration is throwing error. Its going to be slow and painful, but I think I can slog through it.